# Spring tool suite 4.17.2 has "CHKJ3000E: WAR Validation Failed" error for web.xml file

Tags: spring-tools-4

I upgraded to STS 4.17.2 and for my WAR project the "Validation" selection from Window-->Preferences and also from the right click project context menu is no longer available.  How can the above error be corrected or hidden.  My project is still able to runs on Tomcat despite the error present.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by not all components of the Eclipse Web Tools project being installed by default into the Spring Tools for Eclipse distributions anymore (due to a general shift towards the Wild Web Developer tooling for web technologies).

You can install those Eclipse Web Tools components back into an Eclipse or Spring Tools for Eclipse instance via the "Install New Software" dialog, select the matching Eclipse release, and search for the Web tools category. There you will find all the features that you might be interested in.

Important side note: Since you mentioned STS 4.17.2 I would like to mention that this version is not the latest one and not on the latest Eclipse version. So if you select the Eclipse update repository in the install dialog, you would have to manually remove the "latest" Eclipse repo URL and add the one that fits your version of Eclipse. Otherwise, you will most likely run into installation errors and all kinds of trouble.